# PUT and DELETE HTTP in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis

Is SharePoint use PUT and Delete HTTP method?

I know both methods are unsafe!! is it right ? , How I can disable that ? What is the affect of disable that on SharePoint?

Comment: I tested Document editing will not work if PUT is disabled. However I cannot find any support article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had implemented it once. There is no harm if you disable it unless you are using those methods using custom code like REST or JQuery.

You can disable in IIS

Below link will give you the entire steps

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/verbs

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I am using jquery and REST , should i disable it ? , in this case , what is the affect if i disable it with using jquery and REST  ?

Comment: Give it a shot... it should work